# Gmail API credentials on Django

Tags: python, django, gmail-api

I have an email script using gmail API that works fine locally.But when I implemented the same on django, I keep getting 
 `raise IOError(_IS_DIR_MESSAGE.format(filename))
IOError: /home/ubuntu/.credentials: Is a directory` 
Here's the credentials function :

```
def get_credentials():
"""Gets valid user credentials from storage.

If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
"""
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'gmail-python.json')
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials
```

Although this works fine locally, Django keeps throwing 
`File "/home/ubuntu/gmailbot/emailbot/gmailbot.py", line 109, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "/home/ubuntu/gmailbot/emailbot/gmailbot.py", line 92, in get_credentials
    credentials = store.get()`
 and `raise IOError(_IS_DIR_MESSAGE.format(filename))
IOError: /home/ubuntu/.credentials: Is a directory`

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import gmailbot

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^send/$',gmailbot.testfunc),
    ]
```

testfunc :

```
def testfunc(request):
    email = request.GET['email']
    ....
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
return HttpResponse(email)
```

Comment: Are you using the same module in your standalone script and with Django?  Or are there two copies of the function?

Comment: using the same module and the same credentials.

Comment: Show us the Django view code that calls your function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Django. I updated my code. Did the update help?

Comment: What user does the web server process execute as, and what is that user's home directory?

Comment: Try printing the `credential_path` value and see if it points to the right file.